# React Router is not rendering component while using electron

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I am trying to develop a Desktop app using Electron + React. I am using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate).

I have defined my route in the routes.js and referred to the component and yet in development it fails to render the page when I click on it.

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/App';
import HomePage from './containers/HomePage';
import PersonFind from './containers/PersonFind';

export default () => (
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/identify" component={PersonFind} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Router>
);
```

PersonFind.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';


class PersonFind extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <h1> Works </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PersonFind;
```

Comment: how do you use the routes.js file then? I do not understand where I would put it to make this whole thing work. Plus it does not export any name just an anonymous function that returns a react component, so I am not sure how one would use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exact` in your index route.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

`/identify` match with both `/` and `/identify`. Since these two routes are inside a `<Switch>`, only first one (HomePage) get rendered.

Comment: Thank you! I am goung to crack open my head because of this error now.